# How install Google Chrome on Scientific Linux?

Tags: software-installation, firefox, chrome, scientific-linux

Is there a way to install and use Google Chrome on a Scientific Linux machine?

Comment: If there's no package for your distro, I guess not. You can build Chromium from source though.

Answer (score 2):

Since Scientific Linux is based on RHEL, you can try to install Chrome using this [manual](http://chrome.richardlloyd.org.uk/). There's a script that automatically download and install latest Google Chrome browser by picking libraries from a more recent released distro and put those libraries in (`/opt/google/chrome/lib`) directory and then you can able to run Google Chrome.

To use it run:

```
# wget http://chrome.richardlloyd.org.uk/install_chrome.sh
# chmod u+x install_chrome.sh
# ./install_chrome.sh
```

Comment: @LoveLearning did it help?

Answer (score 0):

You can always download the .rpm from the [official download page](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/desktop/), then install it, and you're ready to go. But to actually *use* it (newer versions), you need to do so on KDE Plasma as it's more stable there than in GNOME, at least until the devs fix this bug. Also see [my question/answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/329385/google-chrome-segmentation-fault-within-a-minute/329422#329422).