# Google Chrome segmentation fault within a minute

Tags: chrome, scientific-linux, core-dump, segmentation-fault

Today I installed Google Chrome 55 (i.e. the latest stable version) on 64-bit SL7.0 using a 64-bit RPM. The problem is that google chrome starts fine (except for an SELinux-related issue which I fixed), but it closes without warning after about a minute. No indication of a crash is shown except for "Google Chrome crashed. Would you like to restore your tabs?" the next time I start it (only to happen again, after a minute), and the following output from the terminal when I start chrome there:

```
$ google-chrome

...

Failed to get crash dump id.
Report Id: 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
$
```

Reinstalling chrome did not fix the problem. Nether did deleting my profile folder so chrome can use the defaults.

This is the output when I ran `systemctl status abrtd -l`:

```
abrtd.service - ABRT Automated Bug Reporting Tool
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/abrtd.service; enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2016-12-10 08:22:53 EAT; 7h ago
 Main PID: 698 (abrtd)
   CGroup: /system.slice/abrtd.service
           └─698 /usr/sbin/abrtd -d -s

Dec 10 15:26:10 localhost.localdomain abrt-server[14419]: Package 'google-chrome-stable' isn't signed with proper key
Dec 10 15:26:10 localhost.localdomain abrt-server[14419]: 'post-create' on '/var/tmp/abrt/ccpp-2016-12-10-15:26:04-13832' exited with 1
Dec 10 15:26:10 localhost.localdomain abrt-server[14419]: Deleting problem directory '/var/tmp/abrt/ccpp-2016-12-10-15:26:04-13832'
Warning: Journal has been rotated since unit was started. Log output is incomplete or unavailable.
```

In particular, *Package 'google-chrome-stable' isn't signed with proper key*: Is this a problem? I downloaded it from google's official site. What should I do now?

Comment: Assuming SL7 uses systemd like RHEL7, use coredumpctl to look at the dump, see [this answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/275662/119298).

Comment: @meuh coredumptcl isn't on my system, and `systemd-coredumptcl list` says: `No coredumps found`. Tried as my home user & root, even started google-chrome again so it can register a core dump, crashed and still no core dumps found.

Comment: Perhaps you have a zero core limit: `ulimit -c`.  Or you may be running abrtd which manages core dumps, check with `systemctl status abrtd`.

Comment: Does `abrt-cli list` show any dumps still around? It looks like abrtd took the core dump then removed it?

Comment: `abrt-cli list` shows me a few dumps unrelated to google-chrome. In the past it would alert me if some program went wrong, but it's not reporting anything for chrome this time. It also said automatic bug reporting was disabled so I ran `abrt-auto-reporting enabled` as root. Then I made chrome crash again - still no report.

Comment: The google signing key is [here](https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub), but I'm not sure how you import it. You might get abrtd to not remove the core by setting `ProcessUnpackaged = yes` in /etc/abrt/abrt-action-save-package-data.conf (and `systemctl restart abrtd`). Or you can try `systemctl stop abrtd` and getting a "normal" core dump. You might need `sysctl -w kernel.core_pattern=core` to override whatever setting abrtd leaves in there.

Comment: So apparently the name of the core file that's supposed to be generated is called 'core', and I can't find it in the filesystem means that no core was dumped at all at the time of crash (and the RLIMIT_CORE was set to 0). I raised the limit to infinity with `ulimit -Hc unlimited` (substitute 'H' with 'S' the second time), set the location to /tmp/core, made chrome crash again, I *think* I found the core file in my home folder. Now what?

Comment: `gdb google-chrome core` and give the command `bt` to see the stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am unable to debug the problem with gdb (`bt` only gives me hexadecimal numbers, not function names).

Since, for the severity of this bug, <s>everyone using the current version should have been affected</s> (Quite a number of people have this bug too, according to the bug tracker). Seeing that a few other people have this problem (on [chrome](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1494232) AND [chromium](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=151904)), I assume this is a Chromium bug and/or something on the computer is causing the problem.

I'm going to file the bug on the [Chromium bug tracker](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/), I bet they're going to fix it. :]

**Update**: [This](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=673117) is the bug report I posted.

**Update #2**: It seems like this is a GNOME-specific issue, and it works fine on KDE Plasma, so that's what I'll be using from now on.

Comment: You can try to run chrome from command line with all plugins disabled to see if makes any difference: `google-chrome-stable --disable-gpu --disable-extensions --disable-d3d11 --disable-local-storage --disable-notifications --disable-offne-pages --disable-plugin-power-saver --disable-plugins-discovery --disable-sync --disable-translate --disable-webgl --no-experiments --no-sandbox`.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion : download vivaldi from vivaldi.com that worked smoothly.Vivaldi was clone of google-chrome.

Comment: Vivaldi (like Opera, Comodo Dragon, etc.) is also built on top of Chromium, which are all technically clones. I tried opera and vivaldi on windows, but I want chrome to sync with my google accounts. I'd rather wait till they release a patch.